# Reduce Electron node-modules / prebuild modules size on production

Tags: electron, node-modules, electron-forge, node-sqlite3

I noticed that 99% of the space in my app.asar comes from node-modules, digging around I found 2 modules sqlite3 and serialport that are the reason for the big size.

As example, sqlite3 takes 74Mb, I found inside some big files that I deleted for testing purposes and production build seems to works fine. deleting just few files plus ignoring all .map files (from node-modules only) I went from 99MB to 20MB which would be wonderful for my purpose if I knew what I was doing.

[image]

I don't know exactly if these files are necessary, in any case, I wonder what would be the best practice to avoid unnecessary files, Ignore extensions, etc...